# How to create a remove/delete function button in javascript? Button that can delete an element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I have A Form in `HTML`. Here's my Code:

```
    <div id="format">
         <form id="myForm" onsubmit="myForm(event)">
         <b>Name:</b></br>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  required="required" ></input></br>
         <b>Phone Number:</b></br>
         <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone"  required="required" ></input></br>
        <b>Birthday:</b></br>
        <input type="date" name="bday" id="bday" required="required" ></input></br>
        <b>Email:</b></br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  required="required" ></input></br>
        <b>Password:</b></br>
        <input type="password" name="pWord" id="pWord" required" ></input></br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="myData()" >Submit</button>

    </form>
        <div id="sample"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my `Javascript` code. In this code, when I trigger the submitted button from html, it will display the info of the user and append a div for each submitted info of the users.

```
var data = [];
var i, item;

function myForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var bday = document.getElementById("bday").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("bday").value;
    var ageValue;




    var Bdate = document.getElementById("bday").value;
    var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
    ageValue = ~~ ((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
    var theBday = document.getElementById("age");
    theBday.innerHTML = ageValue;


    var userObject = {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        bday: bday,
        email: email,
        pWord: pWord,
        ageValue: ageValue,

    };
       data.push(userObject);

        document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = ""; //Prevents duplicate
        for (var i=0 ; i <data.length ; i++){
            var theDiv ;
            var container ;
            var button;

            theDiv = document.createElement( "div" );
            button = document.createElement( "button");
            button.setAttribute("id", "remove");
            button.remove(sample);
            theDiv.style = "background-color:pink; border-style:solid; margin:1%;";

            for (item in data[i]) {
                var x = item + ":" + data[i][item] + "</br>" ;              

                theDiv.innerHTML += item + ":" + data[i][item] + "</br>" ;

            }
            button.innerHTML += "Remove";   
            button.style = "background-color:maroon; color:white;"; 

            container = document.getElementById( "sample" );
            container.appendChild( theDiv );
            theDiv.appendChild (button);
        }


    console.log(data);

}
```

I want to to create a button for each appended `div`. The button will have the function of removing the entire div where the button belong.

Comment: Avoid [using "for...in" to iterate over an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5217142). Don't attempt to assign the same `id` attrribute to more than one element. The  ` button.remove(sample);` is pseudo code. Have you tried to implement it? Should the `userObject` entry in the `data[]` array for the button also be removed?

Comment: Ok  i got it, sorry i'm not familiarize with the pseudo code. The userObject entry in the data[] array should remove if the button was trigger

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably simple algorithm to correctly remove objects from the list is to provide a [`data-` attribute value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on each remove botton that gives its *original* index in the data array. (The attribute name used below is `data-index`).

Then take the inline code that adds objects and turn it into three functions to

- (re-)draw **all** objects held in the `data` array.
- add a single object to `data` and redraw all objects.
- remove an object from the data array (coded as a remove button `onclick` handler) and redraw all objects.

The code already redraws all object when adding a new object is added, so redrawing everything when removing an object keeps it on the same level of simplicity.

---

**Example code for simplified form:**

```js
"use strict";
var data = [];

function myFormData(event){

    // halper functions
    function addData( userObject) {
        data.push(userObject);
        redrawList();
    }
    function removeData( event) {
       var index = this.getAttribute("data-index");
       data.splice( index,1);
       redrawList();
    }
    function redrawList() {
        var container = document.getElementById( "sample" );
        container.innerHTML = ""; // reset list displayed on page
        for (var index=0 ; index <data.length ; index++){
            var theDiv = document.createElement( "div" );
            var divHTML = "";
            var button = document.createElement( "button");
            var userObject = data[index];

            for( var item in userObject) {
                if( !userObject.hasOwnProperty( item)) {
                     continue; // ignore inherited properties
                }
                divHTML +=  item + ":" + userObject[item] + "</br>" ;
            }
            theDiv.innerHTML = divHTML;
            theDiv.style = "background-color:pink; border-style:solid; margin:1%;";
            button.type="button";
            button.setAttribute("data-index", index);
            button.innerHTML = "remove";
            button.style = "background-color:maroon; color:white;";
            button.onclick=removeData;   
            theDiv.appendChild (button);
            container.appendChild( theDiv );
        }
    }

    //  handle form submit event to add an event
    event.preventDefault();
    // cut down form:
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var userObject = {
        name: name
    };
    addData( userObject);
    // console.log(data);  // not used in code example
}
```

```html
<div id="format">
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="myFormData(event);">
    <b>Name:</b></br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  required="required" ></input></br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"
      onsubmit="myFormData(event)" >Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div id="sample">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the code uses `getAttribute("data-index")` in case target browser support  for [`element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Browser_compatibility) is unknown or absent. Function names `myForm` and `myData` were changed to `myFormData` as I presume they are the same function.

Probable issue: the existing code comment that clearing the sample list prevents duplicates is wrong. In the example code, clicking the submit button multiple times adds the same user. You could add a test to check for duplicate email addresses when adding a user to the list, but such code is outside the scope of this question. You may also wish to consider resetting the form after adding  data to the "sample" list.

Comment: the program becomes stable. Thanks. Can i ask another question? I want to use console.log to show the deleted user's details 
For Example
I entered 3 users
User 1: John 
User 2: Matt
User 3: Joy

then i remove Matt, I want User 2 to display in the console. thanks

Comment: That should be easy - but please try writing some code to do it yourself. Studying the algorithm to the point of understanding it should help determining where to put the code. See "asking" in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: I already did that. hahaha it's so nice to discover codes. I'm a beginner in arrays and loops. Thaanks

Answer (score 0):

check the [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/fra9Lutt/2/), i have implemented with a single value 'name'.

```js
var data = [];
var i, item;

function myForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   
    var userObject = {
        name: name
        };
       data.push(userObject);

        document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = ""; //Prevents duplicate
        for (var i=0 ; i <data.length ; i++){
            var theDiv ;
            var container ;
            var button;
            var index;

            theDiv = document.createElement( "div" );
            button = document.createElement( "button");
            index = document.createElement("input");
            index.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
            button.setAttribute("id", "remove");
            button.setAttribute("onclick", "removeItem(this)");            

            for (item in data[i]) {
             var x = item + ":" + data[i][item] + "</br>" ;              
                theDiv.innerHTML += item + ":" + data[i][item] + "</br>" ;
                index.value += i; 

            }
            button.innerHTML += "Remove";   
           
            container = document.getElementById( "sample" );
            container.appendChild( theDiv );
            theDiv.appendChild (button);
            theDiv.appendChild(index);
        }
}
function removeItem(event){
 let el = event;
    let index = el.parentNode.lastElementChild.value;
    el.parentElement.remove();
    data.splice(index,1);
}
```

```html
   <div id="format">
         <form id="myForm" onsubmit="myForm(event)">
         <b>Name:</b>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  required="required" >
        
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="myData()" >Submit</button>

    </form>
        <div id="sample"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok i get it now. Thank you! :D

Comment: Not fully debugged. The value in the hidden input is the `data[]` index when the sample was created. This is not constant if you later remove preceding entries in the array. If you "delete"  elements starting from the first, and then add another entry, the entries for data entries removed from the sample container, but not the data array, re-appear.

Comment: @traktor53 Yes it appears that there is a bug in the program. I tried this, time goes by , some of data that should be deleted re appears and replacing the other data

Comment: @akhilaravind when i console your program, i noticed that there are some issues in the objects in the array, the program only remove the current [0] index in the array whether what div i choose to delete, it only delete specifically in  terms of html, but not in the console log. Anyway thank you for the effort, i appreciate it.